# Mysql drop permission for Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We are running a Wordpress site and one of the plug-ins requires drop permission on the database.  (We currently do not grant drop permission and have not needed to for any other plug-ins.)

Is there a security concern if I grant the public connection/user drop privileges?

The plug-in in question is simplepress and we receive an error asking for drop permissions:

> [DROP command denied to user xxxxxxx for table 'wp_sfwaiting'] TRUNCATE wp-sfwaiting

Comment: That sounds odd - why would a *plugin* need to drop the database (unless it's a self-destruct button or something)? What is its task?

Comment: Sure, if WP's user has drop privileges, then everything that user has access to can be nuked. I'd call that a fairly big security concern. A public-facing account should never ever have that kind of access to the db. If it's required for some plugin, then that plugin has an inflated sense of self-importance.

Comment: I've inquired on the simplepress plug-in site as to why they require the drop permission.  Will update if I receive a response.

Comment: For the record -- Response from simplepress forum: The table in question, sfwaiting, holds the admin queue list of new unread posts for the admins…  when the rows in the table need to be removed, the mysql truncate command is used… its the standard mysql command for emptying a table… There will be a couple of other places (may not affect you) that use truncate too…

you could, of course, go edit the code and change the mysql truncate usage to other commands to empty the table in question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mysql` changed in that it requires `DROP` permission since  5.1.16:
[Check it here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html)

`Truncate` is often used as a fast table clear option (as recommended by `MySQL` themselves). It should be changed to `delete from <table>` by that plugin programmer to get away only with the `DELETE` permission.

Until that you may grant drop only for that specific table..